# Which inherited class called function?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance

I want to find out the name of the class of an object from within a function that called that function. I am using John Resig's [class inheritance concept](http://pastebin.com/YdyGPv32).

For example

```
var CoreStuff = Class.extend({ log: function(Message) { console.log(who + ' said ' + Message); });

var MyApp = CoreStuff.extend({ init: function() { this.log('Hello world!'); });

var app = new MyApp();
```

How do I find out if `MyApp` or `CoreStuff` or any other object called `log()` within the hierarchy?

I don't want to pass any more parameters with the current class as I do that currently.

Comment: The object that calls it will be `app`.  If you want to know what function it is coming from, you can pass the name of the function in when you log it, since you control the function

Comment: @ben336 "I don't want to pass any more parameters with the current class as I do that currently." I already pass the current object as a second parameter which I think I can get around, which is why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var CoreStuff = Class.extend({ log: function(Message) { 
                                         console.log(this.constructor.className + ' said ' + Message);                        }
                                    });
CoreStuff.className = "Core Stuff";    

var MyApp = CoreStuff.extend({ init: function() { this.log('Hello world!'); }});
MyApp.className = "My App";
```

Comment: I was thinking of going down the path of your second option but taking it a step further and automatically adding className to the class using the inheritance script. Do you think you could extend that second method?

Comment: Alright that looks like it could work but when I implemented it, it simply returned "Class" for every call. I believe the inheritance method is the culprit. Could you fit your updated method into the inheritance method?

Comment: I've looked at the Class implementation. It seems like we cannot implement your requirement, as the value returned by Class.extend is function Class, the object that we pass in is used to populate the prototype property of function Class => so when we create a new object, the object's constructor is always Class and inherits from the prototype object.

Comment: Class.extend has no way to know your class name if you don't give it information. var CoreStuff and var MyApp are just to store the returned value.

Comment: Damn. I may have to look into other implementations of class inheritance in JavaScript, or maybe just get around this limitation. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem old, but in case anyone still wonders I encountered the issue recently. The reason why everything is called `Class` is because of the way that anonymous functions are used in John's script.

I've written an article about it here: http://www.nicolasbize.com/blog/javascript-inheritance-without-loosing-class-names/

And the proof of concept as a small js framework on github: http://www.nicolasbize.com/moojs